# khttp in Kotlin, java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException when going HTTPS

Tags: kotlin, gradle, khttp, inaccessibleobjectexception

I am experimenting with `khttp` package for Kotlin using Jetbrains IDEA. It works fine with any HTTP url but when I try HTTPS urls it flips up. Please suggest a workaround?

Following those:
https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/khttp

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.danilopianini:khttp:1.4.2")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    ...
}
```

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(khttp.get("https://ifconfig.me/all"))
    ...
}
```

Comment: The [khttp](https://github.com/lojewalo/khttp) repo shows no commits since June 2020. It may simply not work on newer versions of Java. Your error suggests the library tries to reflectively access the internals of JDK classes, something the module system prevents unless explicitly allowed or overridden. From Java 9 to 15, a warning was emitted when this illegal access occurred. Java 16 denied illegal access by default. And for Java 17+, you can no longer change the behavior with `--illegal-access`. Though you can still override this behavior for _specific_ packages via `--add-opens`.

Comment: There are [a few issues](https://github.com/lojewalo/khttp/issues) open that deal with this illegal access problem, but as stated, the project seems dead, so those issues are unlikely to be fixed. Maybe you can [find a fork](https://github.com/lojewalo/khttp/forks?include=active&page=1&period=2y&sort_by=stargazer_counts) that solves the problem. Or you should look for a different HTTP client library. Or, I suppose, you could downgrade Java (this would be my last choice).